# Dynamically creating mutiple Highcharts charts in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

In my directive template I have

```
<div id="chartdiv-{{name}}" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

where name is variable and assigned to each directive when it is created.

The chart is created with

```
 $('#chartdiv-'+scope.name).highcharts(settings);
```

But this doesn't work. Everything works fine if I don't use the `name` variable. Any ideas?

Comment: would it not be `id="chartdiv-{{$scope.name}}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it like this,

```
<div id="{{ 'chartdiv-' + name }}"></div>
```

**EDIT**

If you are creating template inside a directive, it should be

```
<div id="chartdiv-{{$scope.name}}"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, still doesn't show anything. If I inspect the div, the name is correct however it's empty, it doesn't contain the chart.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I just created a plunk and it worked, the difference is that I'm creating the chart in a directive. By the way, it worked both ways, the problem is different.

Comment: @ps0604  if you are doing in an directive it should be id="chartdiv-{{$scope.name}}"

Comment: `$scope.name` or `scope.name`? it didn't work either way

Comment: @ps0604 can i get team viewer?

Comment: I created this directive and it worked, that means that I have a problem somewhere else http://plnkr.co/edit/JVtGtICpKjLNbTDsyMPg?p=preview